# Batch insert entity with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having these classes:

```java
public class SomeCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private Long objectAId;
    private Long objectBId;
    private Long objectCId;
}
```

```java
//lombok annotations~~
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects_assoc")
@IdClass(SomeCompositeKey.class)
public class ObjectsAssocEntity {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_a_id")
    private ObjectAEntity objectA;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_b_id")
    private ObjectBEntity objectB;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_c_id")
    private ObjectCEntity objectC;

}
```

I'm fetching references of `ObjectsAssocEntity` members using `EntityManager.getReference()` and trying to save few entities at once using `saveAll` method, and each time hibernate executes select to check wheter entity exists or not and then make single insert in case when it not exists.

Is there any possibility to use batch insert in this case? Or should I try to do this e.g with native query?

Comment: What hibernate dialect, hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Dialect: SQLServer2012Dialect, Hibernate version: 5.4.15

Comment: The batch insertion isn't related to the previous selected statements. You can check it by analyzing the insert operation after the selects. Add the property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics = true and analyze the insert log to confirm that the batch has been executed. Regarding the selects executed before the batch insert, I'm facing the same problem, just like you. As soon as I have a solution or a understanding. I'll send you the answer!

Answer (score 6):

As described in docs. The spring default implementation must know if the entity is new or not.

In the case of unique primary key: It's easier for spring determine if it's new because before insert the entity id is null.

In the case of a composite key: The ID values are always filled in before persist. So in this case, for determine if the entity is new or not, you can do one of the following approachs:

1. Use a @Version property in the entity class. For a new object, version is null. So that's enough.
2. Implement Persistable interface
3. Override the default spring SimpleJpaRepository EntityInformation and registering as a bean.

Suggestion: @Version has several benefits in the concurrency world. So use it.

[Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies)